# Query regarding "simpleaffy"

Tags: r

I am new to R. I want to use "BART(bioinformatics array research tool)"- an interactive tool using .app file in R. For this, I have to install "simpleaffy" package. I am using the following code for the installation of "simpleaffy":

```
BiocManager::install(version="3.15")
BiocManager::install("simpleaffy")
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(simpleaffy))
```

But after running this code,

```
> BiocManager::install("simpleaffy")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Installing package(s) 'simpleaffy'
Warning message:
package ‘simpleaffy’ is not available for Bioconductor version '3.15'

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages.
```

Please help me in sorting this issue.
Moreover, is it possible to have different versions of the bioconductor at the same time while using a particular version of R?